# Extract a number from line

Tags: ksh

Can you please help me to extract a number from a line:

```
M3ZBA #M440AALM 0600 02/01 HOLD 10 02/01 0:03 4 0 1 02/01/18 ; #60; -M3ZBA#IM3ZRES1-; -2 M3ZBA#IM3ZRES2-
                                                               ^^^
                                                             match these
```

keep in mind the number i try to extract is always AFTER a **"#"** symbol, it's only a number (like **#980** or **#2987** no string), the position can change in the line, but it is always after "#" symbol.

I tried this

```
echo "M3ZBA #M440AALM 0600 02/01 HOLD 10 02/01 0:03 4 0 1 02/01/18 ; #60; -M3ZBA#IM3ZRES1- "| 
   awk -F"; " '{print $2}' 
# Result: #60
```

But i don't like this solution because it's positional solution, i need a string(number) match solution.

I'm using `ksh` on 7.1 `aix` server

Thank you,

Comment: Your question shows no effort by your end. Please show us what you have tried so far and why it's not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what you have tried. Comments can be deleted.

Comment: I think this is a case where you probably want to use regular expressions. If you can say that the result you want is _always_ "#" followed **immediately** by **only** digits then you might be able to use the built-in regex or `egrep`. For example a naive PCRE match is `i/#\d+/`. A more aggressive expression might be `\*\*(#\d+)\*\*;` if the semi-colon and asterisks are also always present. And so on...

Comment: @jdv I edited the question, the `**`..`**` asterisks were only for making the `#60` bold (I hope).  So the more aggressive solution is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's only one matching pattern in the line, eg, you won't see something like `".... #64 ... #865 ..."`, I'd probably use `sed` to strip away everything but the pattern you're looking for ...

- the pattern you want is a `#` followed by 1+ digits so this should suffice: `#[0-9][0-9]*`
- however, we need to keep in mind that a `#` represents the beginning of a comment so we need to escape it in order to treat it as a literal value: `\#[0-9][0-9]*`
- bracket the pattern you want to keep with `\(` and `\)`: `\(\#[0-9][0-9]*\)`
- match the rest of the line (before/after your pattern) with a zero-or-more character wildcard (`.*`): `.*\(\#[0-9][0-9]*\).*`
- since we only have one pattern bracketed with the `\(` and `\)` pairs, this is referred to as pattern #1 and is referenced with an escaped number 1: `\1`
- `sed` will normally echo all input to stdout so we want to run in silent mode (ie, don't echo input to stdout): `sed -n`
- all that's left is to `s`earch for your pattern and `p`rint it (sans the rest of the line) when you find it: `sed -n 's/.*\(\#[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p'`

```
$ echo "M3ZBA #M440AALM 0600 02/01 HOLD 10 02/01 0:03 4 0 1 02/01/18 ; #60; -M3ZBA#IM3ZRES1- " | sed -n 's/.*\(\#[0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
#60
```

And if you don't want the `#` in your output, move the `\#` to the outside of pattern #1, eg:

```
$ echo "M3ZBA #M440AALM 0600 02/01 HOLD 10 02/01 0:03 4 0 1 02/01/18 ; #60; -M3ZBA#IM3ZRES1- " | sed -n 's/.*\#\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
60
```

Here's a [ksh fiddle](http://tpcg.io/57o0XP) - hit 'Execute' button in top left corner

Comment: @blue_iceberg Please accept the answer so other people will not start thinking how to help you.